# How to write mysql OR query using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have product table with product name and foreign key column named as subcategory I want to get product based on subcategory id and product name  using or condition in codeigniter  query method I wrote query for that but it is retrieving two record but i need only one record 
  for example  we have table:

```
 productid   product  subcategory

    1       A           1

    2       A           3

    3       B           3
```

$var="some value from form(1 or 3)";

case 1:  if product='A'  and subcategory($var)=1  or subcategory ($var)=3 then it should get record with productid=1

case2 :if product='A' and subcategory($var)=2 or subcategory ($var)=3 then it should get record for productid=2  because we are using or condition it should check 1 or 3

the query which I have used it is retrieving two records but I need only one record if subcategory =1 or 3

Query:

```
$this->db->where('product', 'A');
$where = '(subcategory="1" or subcategory = "3")';           
$this->db->where($where);
$this->db->get('product');
$query = $gsm_pricing = $query->row();
```

Comment: Pretty sure codeigniter supports something like `or_where()` , `whereOR()` or `ORWhere()` ...

Comment: @RaymondNijland i tried that but getting two records but Ineed only one record without using limit

Comment: *"i tried that but getting two records but Ineed only one record without using limit "* Why not simply using limit?  Or do you mean that you need two record per group?

Comment: see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query solved my issue

```
  $this->db->query(select * from product where product='A' 
  and subcategory='1' 
  union all 
  select * from product where product='A' and subcategory='3' 
  and not exists(select 1 from product where subcategory='1' and prodduct='A'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using " group by productid " in your Query